# What should I do if I accidentally start a war?

Tags: civilization-5

I accidentally started a war with another civ that I was friends with. What can I do to make that civ friendly with me again besides signing a peace treaty?

Comment: Your best bet would be to simply load the previous save game. From my experience with Civ, I've never managed to make peace or forge an alliance with the AI; they always refused unless they're the ones who asked.

Comment: @Nolonar Not true, I often make peace with AIs. Heck, they often are so desperate when I go to them I can ask for cities and they accept!

Comment: How late on in the game is this, and do you have time victory enabled?

Comment: I'm in 1400 A.D. I'm friends with Spain and accidentally tresspassed and clicked yes startvwar instead of no. I nigociated peace and gave the AI two rescourses wine and silk for free and she changed from quarded to neutral.. BTW I never saved my game lol

Comment: Oh I just found the load option from auto saves.. Thabks

Comment: @FezodgeIII. It *is* true, though. I was talking about *my* experience with the game, not about what is or isn't possible. Every time ***I*** ask for peace, the AI refuses saying he'll be crushing me soon, then I conquer their capital before my turn ends, and next turn they beg me to take one of their other cities in return for peace.

Comment: You should accidentally kill the civ you declared war to...

Comment: @Nolonar My bad, missed that part!

Comment: Lmao I might just do that

Comment: I'm not sure if you should even bother and try anything. The diplomatic system in Civ 5 is, let's say strange at times. Your best bet is probably signing the treaty and just wait and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Some leader personalities will accept a lite warring without penalty while others will condemn you for wars *they* Declare. Thus, it depends.

Start by trading a peace deal in their favor. Next, give them another favorable trade. Beyond that, your best bet is to follow the normal diplomatic path to friendship: declare friendship with their friends and them, denounce their enemies, and make more favorable trades after the old benefits disappear